Confused about the law of a random variable
Random variables are measurable functions. So suppose we have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$. $X=Y$ means they are equal as functions.
Explicitly it means $X:(\Omega, A_1) \longrightarrow (E, F_1)$, $Y:(\Omega, A_2) \longrightarrow (E, F_2)$. (with the same domains $\Omega$ and codomains $E$, also we have $X(w)=Y(w), \forall w \in \Omega$.)
Q1: Do we need $A_1=A_2, F_1=F_2$?
Q2: It is stated that if $X=Y$, then they have the same law. I do not understand the reason why. Law is a measure function, so to guarantee two laws are equal,
we need $F_1=F_2$ at least. But it seems still not enough.  Suppose $X:(\Omega, A_1) \longrightarrow (E, F, P_1)$, $Y:(\Omega, A_2, P_2) \longrightarrow (E, F)$.
The law $P_X(A)=P_1(X^{-1}(A)) \neq P_2(Y^{-1}(A))=P_Y(A)$ if $P_1 \neq P_2$

If you just say "random variable" you assume the codomain is $\mathbb R$ with the Borel sets.

Not a probabilist here but your objection in question 2 looks valid, which means that we should call a random variable a morphism in the category of measure spaces, and not merely a map, that is to say a morphism in the category of sets.
So the answer appears to be yes to Q1, and you must add $P_1 = P_2$, and then it becomes true that if the random variables are equal, they have the same law.
